# Plot polygons + timestamp on a map with time-slider

Tags: leaflet, plotly, anychart

I have list of locations/polygons with timestamp for each one.

I want to plot those on a map but also have a 'time-slider" that is from my earliest event until my last event that I can “drag” and see only the events relevant to this time.

I would like the slider to be or 1 tick per event or have it in ticks of hours so I can see only the events in each hour

is that possible using any out of the box libraries (plotly, anychart, leaflet)?

Comment: Do the polygons are equal to map regions like states/provinces? I mean like in the samples in this article - https://docs.anychart.com/Maps/Choropleth_Map 
Or polygons are related to any specific region which is not equal to state/province?

Comment: polygons are geometries with list of coordinates.. like locationtech.geom of java or something like that.

Comment: Unfortunately, the current version of AnyMap 8.5.1 doesn't provide a possibility to render custom polygons under the SVG map. This is an interesting case, we will look into it.

Comment: And if it's only points?

Comment: If they are points, you can use a dot series on a map. The points are related to geo coordinates. For details, you can check the following article about this series type - https://docs.anychart.com/Maps/Dot_(Point)_Map  If this series type suits you, let us know if any assistance is required.

Comment: Yes, I want to have a time slider so I can can move it and see the points move in time (I have time stamp for each point).

Comment: ok! this is an interesting case, we will take some time to prepare a sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this sample](https://playground.anychart.com/Y1ALvGTN) you can choose which points will be shown on the map by changing the slider's value.

We hope this answer will help you.

Comment: Stack Exchange discourages link-only answers. Please include a description of _what_ that example does